# Django Weird behavior while extracting last element from a list at views.py

Tags: django, django-views

I have created a blog with Django, I want my last published post appears at the first page. Here is my views.py code:

```
   def index(request):
       messages = get_list_or_404(Message.objects.order_by('publication_date'))
       last = messages[-1]
       return render_to_response('posts/index.html', {
          'last_message' : last,                                                        
          'posts_list'   : messages,
       })
```

But I don't understand why, while pressing F5 on this page, it prints the last post (as expected) or the first one (without any obvious reason) randomly (sometime the last post, sometime the first one).

This behavior occurs with apache2 running with mod_wsgi and not with django development server (which displays always the last post).

Does anyone have any clue?

Many thanks

Edit: Here is the code I use in my index.html template:

```
{% if last_message %}
 <article>
 <h1><a href="/posts/{{ last_message.id }}">{{ last_message.title }}</a></h1>
 <p class="meta_infos">Published on {{ last_message.publication_date }}</p>
 <p>{{ last_message.text }}</p>
 </article>
{% else %}
 <p>No post available</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you check the data to see is there any row with the publication_date being null?

Comment: I have couple questions: 1) is the code hosted on single server or multiple ones (eg. you have round-robin in the DNS records, or your load balancer sometimes directs you to the correct server, sometimes to the "wrong" one)?, 2) have you reloaded Apache configuration after implementing change on every server?, 3) what exactly changes (maybe the protocol, maybe small part of the URL)?, 4) what is in the template you are using (probably unrelated, but maybe worth asking)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there is any row with publication_data null.

Comment: Tadeck, my code is hosted in only one virtual server running one apache VirtualHost. The only think which changes is the post being displayed, the first saved one instead of the last one, when i press F5 several times. In my template, I have only html code and {{ post.title }} tags

Comment: What happens if you change the variable name "last" to "last_message"? I'm not sure why the code highlighter is picking up on "last", but it's one more thing to eliminate. If you do have messages without a publication_date, those should be filtered out, e.g., `Message.objects.filter(publication_date__isnull=False).order_by('-publication_date')`

Comment: No, same behavior with different unambiguous variable name lastm. And same thing with the filter you propose :( I can't see any reason to explain this random display

Comment: Can you post your Message model class?

Comment: This might be useless; the issue was solved by a apache reload. There must be some kind of cache or something with this server, contrary to django development server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oki, guys, the problem came from apache server which needed to be reloaded (there is no need to do so with PHP, that's why I haven't thought of it).

I also have replaced
    messages = get_list_or_404(Message.objects.order_by('publication_date'))
by
    last = get_list_or_404(Message).latest('publication_date')
Which is more concise.

Thanks for your help and answers!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way to ensure you're only pulling back one object instead of all the messages each time:

```
messages = Message.objects.order_by('-publication_date')[:1]
if not messages:
    raise Http404
last = message[0]
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
try:
    last = Message.objects.order_by('-publication_date')[0]
except IndexError:
    raise Http404
```

Comment: It does not actually explain why the issue is happening, this is only a walkaround.

Comment: No, but it solves the problem the OP has. Without seeing more code it's hard to figure out why that's happening, but I don't think he's looking to recreate the behavior, just fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, guys,
Tom, your second code lower the effect without fixing it totally. But sometimes, while pressing F5, the first post appears instead of the last one. I edit my question to add my template code (even if I don't think it would be helping much)